# Unable to get Jest test to pass in Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, jqwidget

This seems so simple that I know I must be doing something wrong, but I've been at this for a whole day, and still can't get a simple test to pass. My component uses the third-party library JQWidgets, and part of the problem is that the test reports an error in that library, but the other part of the test failure is that apparently my mock data that's supposed to load into a property in the component isn't getting in there.

I'm trying to use Jest mocks, but even though I've read over the documentation a dozen times by now, I'm still not sure I'm doing it right. Sometimes I need a spy, and sometimes I just want the mocked function (usually a service function) to return some dummy data. I feel like I just don't understand some of the Jest mocking magic perhaps.

I apologize for any vagueness, and I wish there was someone at my work I could ask, but there isn't, so I'm humbly reaching out for help.

**EDIT: mock the whole service** This appears to be working better, insomuch as as my test assertions are passing, but the test is still failing because of an error in the third-party module. I've tried adding NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA but it doesn't help:

```
TypeError: bA.getPropertyValue is not a function
      at R (node_modules/jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js:14:36743)
```

**Component's ngOnInit()**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._dataService.getData().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.populate(data); // <--this line appears not to be running, as this function populates this.source.localdata with this data
        this.dataAdapter = new jqx.dataAdapter(this.source);
      },
      error => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

**My test**

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { jqxGridComponent } from 'jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets-ts/angular_jqxgrid';
import { ProgressComponent } from './progress.component';
import { ProgressGridDataService } from './progress.service';
import { WorkingFileService } from 'src/app/services/working-file/working-file.service';
import { IProgressData } from './progress.interfaces';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

describe('ProgressComponent', () => {
  let component: ProgressComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProgressComponent>;

  class ProgressServiceSpy {
    testHistory: IProgressData = {
      recordId: 1,
      product: 'A',
    };
    getData = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => of(Object.assign({}, this.testHistory)));

    restartLoad = jest.fn();
  }
  beforeEach(
    async(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ProgressComponent, jqxGridComponent],
        providers: [
          WorkingFileService,
          { provide: ProgressGridDataService, useValue: {} },
        ],
      })
      .overrideComponent(ProgressComponent, {
        set: {
          providers: [
            { provide: ProgressGridDataService, useClass: ProgressServiceSpy },
          ],
        },
      })
      .compileComponents();
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProgressComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();
    })
  );

  describe('retry button', () => {
    it('should call the restartLoad service and pass a record ID', () => {
      component.ngOnInit();
     expect(component.source).toHaveProperty('localdata');
      expect(component.source.localdata).toEqual(testHistory);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. For one thing, it seems suspect that you use real collaborators and apparently need to use `HttpClientTestingModule` when testing a *component*, not a service.

Comment: @jonrsharpe even that is a bit over my head. Previously I was trying to follow some Angular documentation examples for testing a service, and that was just left in there. I switched to HttpClientModule

Answer (score 2):

I managed to figure it out with some further digging. I followed the example of the [Angular Stackblitz Hero app](https://stackblitz.com/angular/qvvpakbqkpp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhero%2Fhero-detail.component.spec.ts) and completely mocked my whole service since it wasn't really under test. I do not understand why that has to use `overrideComponent` to set the spy service instead of just doing that in the TestBed configuration, but I think it's because my component has the service in its own `providers` array ([docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing#override-component-providers)).

As to the weird `bA.getPropertyValue is not a function` error, [this Github issue](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/1505) set me on the right track so that I was able to add this snippet to `jestGlobalMocks.ts` and then finally my test was passing!

I wish to heaven I knew better what I was doing with testing in Angular with Jest, because spending a solid 8 hours just to get this tiny test running and passing is the very reason my application is so lacking in test coverage.

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'getComputedStyle', {
  value: () => ({
    getPropertyValue: prop => {
      return '';
    },
  }),
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You should get the service reference from TestBed and then mock or SpyOn it:

```
    import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { jqxGridComponent } from 'jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets-ts/angular_jqxgrid';
import { ProgressComponent } from './progress.component';
import { ProgressGridDataService } from './progress.service';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { IProgressData } from './progress.interfaces';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

describe('ProgressComponent', () => {
  let component: ProgressComponent;
  let progressService: ProgressGridDataService;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProgressComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ProgressComponent, jqxGridComponent],
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [ProgressGridDataService, WorkingFileService],
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProgressComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    progressService = TestBed.get(ProgressGridDataService); // Here get the service
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  describe('component load', () => {
    let testHistory: IProgressData;

    beforeEach(() => {
      testHistory = {
        recordId: 1,
        product: 'A',
        fileId: 'A',     
      };
    });
    it('should pull the data from the service into a component property', () => {
     //I'm trying to use a Jest mock function, but I'm not sure I'm using it right 

  //Mock and Spy now....

      jest.spyOn(progressService, 'getData').mockImplementation(() => of(testHistory));
      component.ngOnInit();

      expect(component.source).toHaveProperty('localdata');
      expect(component.source.localdata).toEqual(testHistory)
      //would love to have an expectation that the service was called properly, but not sure how to do Jest spies on that function correctly.
       });
      });
    });
```

Comment: In my component though I've got the service in `providers` (although I'm not really sure why except it works), and in the Angular docs (https://angular.io/guide/testing#get-injected-services) they say to get the service from the component's injector in this case.

Comment: That's ok. you are configuring your TestModule here so you should get the service from TestBed. As per documentation: You may also be able to get the service from the root injector via `TestBed.get()`. This is easier to remember and less verbose. But it only works when Angular injects the component with the service instance in the test's root injector.